# AngularJS ControllerAs syntax and controller injected variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-controlleras

I'm writing a directive and trying to stick to the [John Papa style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide). So I've also decided to jump on the `ControllerAs` syntax wagon and I've got a tiny directive like below:

```
(function() {
    angular
        .module('htApp')
        .directive('newsletterSignup', newsletter_signup);

    function newsletter_signup($http) {
        var directive = {
            templateUrl: '../whatever.tpl.html',
            restrict: 'EA',
            controller : controller,
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            bindToController: true
        };

        return directive;

        controller.$inject = ['$http'];

        function controller($http) {
            var vm = this;
            // $http is here ... all is good, but I don't need it

            function doSubmit(form) {
                // I need $http here, but it is null
                debugger;
            };

            vm.doSubmit = doSubmit;
        }
    }
})();
```

This is a newsletter signup service. I'm going to have to do an HTTP request, therefore I'm injecting it into the controller. All is fine - but calling the `vm.doSubmit(--formname-here--)` function from the template results in me not being able to find the `$http` service.

So my question: how can I access the injected `$http` from the `doSubmit()` function?

**EDIT**

I'll include the view code - but no worries - the plumbing works:

```
<button class="btn btn-yellow" ng-click="vm.doSubmit(newsletterform)" translate>
    footer.ok_button_text
</button>
```

**EDIT 2**

As it turns out, @Tek was right - the code works. I think the reason I didn't see it was because (I think) the JS runtime in Chrome optimizes the `$http` away when it knows it's not going to be called.

[image: code_works]

This code works fine. I think this is because the runtime aniticipated the usage of `$http` in the `console.log()` function call. However - if I remove that line I get this ( which was why I had this problem in the first place ):

[image: $http not available]

Notice that I commented out the `console.log` - thus the `doSubmit()` call never uses `$http`. Now - when I call `$http` in the console - it's not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example works just fine: [example](http://jsbin.com/manile/edit?js,output).

But as for me John Papa has pretty strange vision of angular style, I prefer [this style guide](http://toddmotto.com/opinionated-angular-js-styleguide-for-teams/).

Comment: That's strange - can't get it to work myself. Interesting style guide - I was just reading this guy's blog this morning. Reason for using John Papa's is because I've heard it will make the transition to Angular v2 easier.

Comment: I figured out what the problem was - you might be interested in my updated question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
return directive;

controller.$inject = ['$http'];

function controller($http) {
...
```

`controller` function is defined when `return` statement is executed. But `controller.$inject` will never be defined. Also, `newsletter_signup` function misses the corresponding `$inject`.

[This](http://plnkr.co/edit/FjfVyNHXllxOm2qqr8CZ?p=preview) won't be [minified](http://plnkr.co/edit/FlRMuz4iM8BhWD68z4RO?p=preview) properly. While [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/OVSIlYUjPj0WjxeDs59n?p=preview) will be [minified](http://plnkr.co/edit/7N89OwL1xeArPPYZe9bF?p=preview).

Comment: thanks but I don't think that's the problem. The code works as it turns out - I think that because of a runtime-optimization, I got the NullRef exception. I'll update my post to demonstrate.

Comment: `$inject` applies to code minification. Minify the code and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks - but like I said - wiring up `$http` works just fine. Also minified. Check out my updated question though - I stumbled upon a nice quirk.

Comment: I guess your question concerns Chrome debugger, not Angular DI. Despite that, your code doesn't match JP style guide, the answer addresses that. I've updated it to make it more clear.

Comment: Good point - I overlooked that. Thank you very much for pointing it out: my code was *not* minifying correctly indeed.

Comment: You're welcome. JP style guide is indeed good for ES5 when done right.